# Twilio trying to check if subscriber is already on the list

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am trying to get check incoming numbers to see if the are already members on my Twilio when a user texts back "subscribe".  However it keeps breaking.  I am trying to have it return to user variable ( broadcastAlreadySubMessage ).  Please take a look at code lines 59 - 67

```
/* global module, exports, require, process, console */

// Response strings - update these to change the copy in the messages
const helpMessage = 'Thy help is here! Text "subscribe" to subscribe. Reply "stop" to stop getting messages, and "start" to receive them again.';
const subscribeSuccessMessage = 'You are now subscribed!';
const subscribeFailMessage = "Dang it. We couldn't subscribe you - try again later?";
const broadcastNotAuthorizedMessage = 'Failed to broadcast';
const broadcastSuccessMessage = 'Success! Your text will be sent immediately.';
const broadcastFailMessage = 'Well this is awkward. Your message failed to send, try again later.';
const broadcastAlreadySubMessage = 'you are already subscribed.';

// Helper class for commands
class Command {
  // Create a new instance with necessary arguments from the incoming SMS
  constructor(event, context) {
    this.fromNumber = event.From;
    this.body = event.Body || '';
    this.event = event;
    this.context = context;

    const client = this.context.getTwilioClient();
    this.notify = client.notify.services(process.env.BROADCAST_NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID);

    /*
     * Occassionally, US numbers will be passed without the preceding
     * country code - check for this eventuality and fix it
     */
    if (this.fromNumber.indexOf('+') !== 0) {
      this.fromNumber = `+1${this.fromNumber}`;
    }
  }

  // Get an array of arguments after the first word for a command
  get commandArguments() {
    return this.body.trim().split(' ').slice(1);
  }

  // Get the full text after the command with spaces reinserted
  get commandText() {
    return this.commandArguments.join(' ');
  }

  // Execute command async (to be overridden by subclasses)
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, 'Command not implemented.');
  }
}

/* Subclasses for supported commands */

class HelpCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, helpMessage);
  }
}

class SubscribeCommand extends Command {
  //bindingResult = client.notify.v1.services(process.env.BROADCAST_NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID).bindings.list().then((bindings) => {
    bindingResult = this.notify.bindings.list().then((bindings) => {
    bindings.forEach(b => {
      if(b.identity === this.fromNumber) { 
        // incoming number  
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
  
  run(callback) {
    
    //execute logic to return "you are already subscribed" message
    // bindingResult.then((r) => {
    //   callback(null, broadcastAlreadySubMessage);
    // });
    
    console.log(bindingResult);

    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    this.notify.bindings
      .create({
        identity: this.fromNumber,
        bindingType: 'sms',
        address: this.fromNumber,
      })
      .then(() => {
        callback(null, subscribeSuccessMessage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, subscribeFailMessage);
      });
  }
}

class BroadcastCommand extends Command {
  constructor(event, context) {
    super(event, context);
    this.adminNumbers = context.BROADCAST_ADMIN_NUMBERS;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  run(callback) {
    /*
     * Check if sender is in list of admins, stored in the system environment
     * as a comma-separated string
     */
    if (this.adminNumbers.indexOf(this.fromNumber) < 0) {
      return callback(null, broadcastNotAuthorizedMessage);
    }

    // Create a new Notification for all bindings with the text of the message
    this.notify.notifications
      .create({
        tag: 'all',
        body: this.commandText,
      })
      .then(() => {
        callback(null, broadcastSuccessMessage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, broadcastFailMessage);
      });
  }
}

// Handle incoming SMS commands
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  // Get command text from incoming SMS body
  let cmd = event.Body || '';
  cmd = cmd.trim().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase();

  // Choose other commands as appropriate
  const CommandClasses = {
    subscribe: SubscribeCommand,
    broadcast: BroadcastCommand,
  };
  const CommandClass = CommandClasses[cmd] || HelpCommand;
  const cmdInstance = new CommandClass(event, context);

  // Execute command
  cmdInstance.run((_err, message) => {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message(message);
    callback(null, twiml);
  });
};
```

I tried entering the code between lines 59 through 67 and got an error message. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...where are the users being saved or stored?

Comment: I will start from the beginning. I am running an SMS Marketing campaign on Twilio. We have a service that allows users to subscribe using the "subscribe" command, the app also allows us to broadcast to our subscribers using the "broadcast" command. Unfortunately, the app doesn't stop people from getting the welcome message once they subscribe over and over - the message is something along the lines of "you have a discount waiting for subscribing". I believe they are added to a list somewhere in Twilio's servers, and their numbers do not get duplicated.

Comment: @lizziepika, I think they get added to a broadcast service in twilio
https://www.twilio.com/blog/store-opt-out-data-twilio-functions-sync